# Advice on buying a second hand camera

Tags: nikon, nikon-d700

is a Nikon d700 with sc < 5k for 950SGD a good buy? What are the things that I should take note of before buying? Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to photo.SE! There is already a general post about second hand equipment that you may find interesting, and about the price I think it's not such a fitting question for the stack exchange format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What a camera is worth depends on local market and what value you place on it.   That said 950 SGD sounds like a good price for a D700 and especially so if you can guarantee the SC < 5k. A 22000 SC unit is for sale here at similar price and I have seen them offered for more than that recently. (I own one so note prices).

I have found [**Steven**](http://changmoh.com/camera-hospital/) of [Camera Hospital in Sunshine Plaza, 91 Bencoolen Street](http://www.camerahospital.com.sg/)  very competent, knowledgeable, friendly and helpful. He may be able to comment on market prices and things to look for.

The D700 is built like a tank. The shutter is rated for 200k+ operations afair (maybe 300k). I do not know if anyone has worked out how to wind back the SC reading but the condition of the camera should be near pristine for genuine 5k. No rubbed body edges etc.

LCD should have a protector on and be scratch free (although this does not rally make as much difference as you may expect. ).

It should have at least one genuine battery and ideally a few. Clone batteries can be OK but fade much more rapidly with age.

Body is nicely weather sealed. Check rubbers on all ports - I've had no issues with mine and I am rougher on my cameras than most so these should be in good order.

Sensor spotting can happen to any camera but seeing how dirty it is can do no harm and may allow a little bargaining due to cost of commercial cleaning. Various means of checking will be on web but method under "sensor dirt check" at end works for me.

I am not aware of any specific issues with D700 shutter but try some shots at high and low shutter speeds.

Check for body cap, manuals, software DVD - but mostly not major aspects if the body proper is OK.

---

**Sensor dirt check:**

- Set camera to small aperture (f/22+?)
- Set to low ISO, so exposure time will be several seconds.
- Set to manual focus at close range
- Point camera at clear blue sky or uniform target, operate shutter and wave camera to & fro randomly across area during exposure.
- Repeat for a 2nd exposure.

Compare (flicker compare is good) two exposures and zoom in as required.
Sensor dirt shows as unvarying spots on both images.